# Multibooting RaspberryPi with OwnCloud,RaspBMC,Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc, noobs

I have tried both NOOBS and Berryboot but I would like to have a say on which distro I want to install to my Pi.
I would like to have it as a NAS with Owncloud when I'm not home and choose between Rasbmc and Raspbian when I want to watch or do some work when at home.

Is it possible?
Is there maybe a way to just add/remove OSes from the specific folder of NOOBS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to buy several SD cards and install the OS of your choice on every card, then you may switch between OSes as simple as removing one SD card and putting in another.

even better solution might be getting several Pis and use one as Onecloud server, another as media player, and third as whatever you like at the moment. I have currently three of them running, beats switching SD cards hands down.

Comment: For Raspbmc and Raspbian it is simple with NOOBS/Berryboot.I have already set it up. It seems that I am gonna need one more Pi then for OwnCloud.